# mod_rewrite to corresponding php files in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’d like to use mod_rewrite (in .htaccess) to map “clean” URLs to their corresponding php files in a subdirectory, for example:

```
https://example.com/test/
-->
https://example.com/p/test.php
```

My first step was to add trailing slashes to all URLs that lack one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Then I added the following lines to make sure the path/file doesn’t exist already:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

And finally the `RewriteRule` that maps the requested path to the corresponding file in the subdirectory `/p/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /p/$1\.php
```

This seems to work fine—unless I’m requesting a URL that doesn’t exist. Then the operation will result in an endless loop such as:

```
https://example.com/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/p/test/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/
```

I’ve already tried adding another `RewriteCond` right before the `RewriteRule` to ensure the requested file actually exists in the subfolder `/p/`, but my approach doesn’t work:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/p/$1.php -f
```

Can anyone please tell me what I’ve been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’ve already tried adding another `RewriteCond` right before the `RewriteRule` to ensure the requested file actually exists in the subfolder `/p/`, but my approach doesn’t work:

Yes, you will need to do that... check that the file you intend to rewrite to actually exists, rather than rewriting anything that simply doesn't exist (which will result in a rewrite loop if the target also does not exist). However, your "problem" is that your URLs end in a trailing slash and you don't appear to be accounting for this in your rule. So, given a request for `/test/` you are effectively trying to test for `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/p/test/.php`, which naturally does not exist.

You need to exclude the trailing slash in the capturing subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
# Rewrite "/test/" to "/p/test.php" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/p/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ p/$1.php [L]
```

There's no need for the additional filesystem checks (and overhead) to check that the request does not map to a file or directory - since these should be mutually exclusive events. (If you did happen to have a directory of the same name then the corresponding `.php` file would otherwise not be accessible.)

Your complete file then becomes:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Append trailing slash (if omitted)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/test/" to "/p/test.php" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/p/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ p/$1.php [L]
```

Note that there is no need for the second condition in the rule that appends the trailing slash to test that the requested URL does not end in a trailing slash, since this is already handled by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (the pattern simply would not match if there was a trailing slash).

And no need for the `RewriteBase` directive here. On the external redirect it is better to be explicit and include the slash prefix on the *substitution* string.

---

*Aside:*

> My first step was to add trailing slashes to all URLs that lack one:

Just to clarify, all your internal links must have already been updated to include the trailing slash, otherwise your users (and search engines) will be unnecessarily redirected all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much, @MrWhite. This was more than I could’ve asked for, and it works perfectly. Indeed, I had overlooked the trailing slash. And your other comments make absolute sense, too. Now it’s much cleaner and way more concise. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs this: I’ve built upon MrWhite’s solution and added another `RewriteRule` that should prevent direct access to any .php files, including the ones in the `/p/` subdirectory. Otherwise users would be able to access the same file under the “clean” URL and its direct path.

The complete code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Append trailing slash (if omitted)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/test/" to "/p/test.php" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/p/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ p/$1.php [END]

# Prevent direct access to php files
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

(I had to slightly change the original code to prevent infinite looping. That’s why I added the `END` flag to the second `RewriteRule`.)

Comment: Good addition +1. Just a couple of minor points... there is no need to use the `L` and `END` flags together. `END` on its own is sufficient (essentially a "stronger" version of `L`).  Your regex in the last rule should be anchored, ie. `\.php$`. `\.php` matches ".php" _anywhere_ in the URL-path, so could potentially match too much, but it is also less efficient. (The `END` flag was new with Apache 2.4. For anyone still using Apache 2.2, there are alternative methods.)

Comment: Thank you, @MrWhite. I edited my answer so that it now includes your suggestions. Works perfectly. And I agree, the `\.php` should be tied to the end, at least for efficiency. I mean, one could go even further and match only URIs with `/p/` in it, but I’d assume that most people who have use for something like this probably prefer to exclude all direct access to .php files.